Interpretation of Ricci curvature $Ric(V, W)$ when $V \neq W$
Let $Ric$ be the Ricci curvature tensor on a Riemannian manifold $M$. I am interested in the geometric interpretation of the Ricci curvature tensor.
The explanation usually given is as follows. Fix $p \in M$ and $V$ in $T_pM$ and consider a small neighborhood $U$ around $V$ in $T_pM$. By taking the union of all geodesics starting at $P$ and in the direction of some tangent vector in $U$ we obtain a rod. If $Ric(V, V) > 0$ then volume of this rod grows more than it would in Euclidean space, meaning the geodesics diverge, so the space has negative curvature in this direction. If $Ric(V, V) < 0$ then the geodesics converge and the space has positive curvature in this direction.
Assuming the above is correct, how can one interpret $Ric(V, W)$ if $V \neq W$? Does this measure how the area of the parallelogram whose sides are $V$ and $W$ change as its transported along geodesics?

Note that algebraically, since Ricci is symmetric, $$Ric(v,w) = \frac12 [Ric(v+w,v+w) - Ric(v,v) - Ric(w,w)]$$ says that Ricci is determined by its values on plugging in the same vector into both places. But of course your question is about interpretation.
